# Easy way to rig a power source switcher for a 110v appliance?

Tags: electrical, appliances

I have a generator and a battery bank with an inverter. I have an appliance which I want to be able to press a button and have it switch power sources between the two. Ideally if there's an extension cord type adapter for this that would be optimal, not sure I want to actually make anything myself. Something like this only the opposite of it:

[image]

It wouldn't surprise me if there isn't a product like what I'm looking for, probably not a common thing. I want it to have two male plugs and one female, with a switch on it to change power course. Anyone have any easy ideas for me if there isn't a product like this? Thanks!

Comment: You're pretty much describing a UPS [Uninterruptible Power Supply] system, but with a manual switch. idk if any UPSes have manual switching, but it might be a place to start looking.

Comment: Does it have to be remote controlled? Otherwise, a DIY box with a "3-way" switch, a receptacle and two wired plugs is theoretically what you want.

Comment: There's also a caveat on the time it takes to switch over - this may be very dependant on what equipment is being powered.

Comment: In addition to"Remote?" and "Switchover time requirement?", the key question I have is **total power being switched**? With physical manual switches (e.g., standard light switches) 15A is no problem, there are a lot of electronic switches that are limited, depending also on type of load (resistive vs. motor, etc.)

Comment: @Tetsujin A UPS is simply a power strip with a battery inside right? They plug into a single power source (1 male connector), at least the ones I've seen. I need something that will plug into two, just with a button at the intersection to switch between them.

Comment: @P2000  manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact It doesn't need to be remote controlled, and it only needs to handle a load of 650 watts. If I have to make one, what would be the most simple way? Ideally using components which don't require special tools like crimpers, soldering gun, etc. Just needs to be two standard male outlet connectors, one female, and a hard switch between them.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact

Comment: I think the big complication here is that you need to switch **both hot and neutral**. Which means a *double pole* switch. But you *also* need what is (in the US) referred to as a *3-way* switch. Getting the two in one device may not be so easy. The alternative is to go to down to the component level - but then you are (usually) talking about crimping or soldering rather than being able to just screw everything together.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact Geez.. maybe I'll just mount the end of two extension cords side-by-side and make it easy to switch plugs. I guess this is an uncommon scenario so I see why there isn't a product like this.

Comment: It would help to know more about the loads, since there are gotchas for certain loads, like gas furnaces.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [double-pole, double-throw switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004WLKA) (link is just as illustration) to transfer the load. As you state, you could build this into a junction box, with two plugs on cords and one receptacle on the box.

[image]

That said, such a switch could cause shock and/or fire hazards if improperly wired. For example, can the grounds of the two power sources be connected together safely? How can you insure a wire will not come loose and cross connect the supplies, so that the generator might be *live* when you think it's off?

From your question, it appears you're not familiar with electronics and electrical wiring. For that reason, I'd suggest you have a licensed electrician review your work if you make this.